# Codeigniter Redirect not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, methods

Let I am in following location

```
http://localhost/ignitershop/index.php/seller_controller/viewcart
```

And here in this view I have a link and using it i want to move to another method of the same controller called removeRow() . So I am using href as below

```
<a href="seller_controller/removeRow" >CLICK TO REMOVE </a>
```

So I expect the new url to be :

```
http://localhost/ignitershop/index.php/seller_controller/removeRow
```

but the url seems to be concatenating. And it is becoming something as below :

```
http://localhost/ignitershop/index.php/seller_controller/seller_controller/removeRow
```

That is seller_controller is coming twice. I am facing such type of concatening problem using redirect also. So I need to know what it is the best way for switching method of the same controller. Any good solution ???

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('seller_controller/removeRow');?>" >CLICK TO REMOVE </a>
```

Or you can also try like

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url().'seller_controller/removeRow';?>" >CLICK TO REMOVE </a>
```

You cont use `base_url()` Because it doesnt included the index page (May be the `index.php` ) where `site_url()` has the combination with `base_url()` and `index url`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the absolute path by using either site_url() or base_url()

Answer (score 0):

Use `ob_start();` at the begging of the script.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening, because your link is relative - i.e. it is added to the current URI minus the last part. Think of it like directories and files - the last part (viewcart) is a file, and the rest is a directory. A relative link means "*Hey, take me to this file (removeRow), but start delving from the current directory*".

This means that if you have `http://localhost/ignitershop/index.php/seller_controller/viewcart` and there you visit a link with content `<a href="one/two/three">Link</a>`, it will send you to `http://localhost/ignitershop/index.php/seller_controller/one/two/three`

To fix it, use `base_url()` or `site_url()` functions from the URL helper accordingly, which will do the job for you. [Check out the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) for more info.